# Refreshing/releasing 2nd tableview from previous query in drill down tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a drill down tableview that is using sqlite.

The first one is a tableview where i load some categories using a SQL query.

When i click a row it's using the following query to show the appropriate records for the category:

@"SELECT * FROM table WHERE category IS ('%@')", sharedSingleton.category];

This works.

When i click the back button on tableview 2 and return to the category tableview and then touch another category tableview2 still shows the rows for the category i selected the first time.

I'm new to this stuff but i searched a long time and tried releasing objects or set value's to nil but is doesn't seem to help.

Am i in the right direction, how can i refresh or release tableview2?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are in the right direction.

When selecting a row table 1 you might be calling a method which loads the second table view and assigning the data to be loaded to the corresponding table view,Which is fetched and filled when delegate/ data source methods of table view is called.

You might have created tableview as a different view controller class, which is initialized and data is reloaded for the first time. But even though you are fetching the second set of data its not getting reloaded automatically even after you are assigning it.

After assigning the data you have fetched into the obect which distributes it to tableview Reload the table data once you assign it to. you could call the one line of code to do this

[tableview reloadData];

Regards,
Jackson Sunny Rodrigues

Comment: Oke, thanks for the quick answer. However, i tried to implement this in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method the result is the same. i also pasted it in viewDidload in the 2nd viewcontroller which doesn't update but then i get a blank screen in that tableview controller. any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Jackson, it's solved! :) i was calling the database in viewDidLoad. I moved it to viewWillAppear and implemented the reloadData you suggested in my 2nd tableview controller and everything is alright. So another thing i learned is that viewDidLoad is called only once. Thanks for your help!